# Swap with out vs ref

Tags: c#, swap

What's the better way of implementing a swap function? How would using ref be better than using out, or vice versa? Any other benefits or drawbacks that will occur from using one or the other?

```
swapref(ref T a, ref T b) {
  T temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp;
}

swapout(out T a, out T b)
{ 
   T temp = a;
   a = b;
   b = temp;
}
```

Comment: `swapout` is illegal (compile-time error) since you try to read `a` before it is definitely assigned!

Comment: Also, unless this is a constructor, you need to specify a return type (such as `void`) before the method name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I modify your `swapout` method to something closer to compiling...

```
static void swapout<T>(out T a, out T b)
{
    T temp = a; // ERROR: Use of unassigned out parameter 'a'
    a = b;      // ERROR: Use of unassigned out parameter 'b'
    b = temp;
}
```

...it still produces the errors you see in the comments.

When a parameter is modified with  `out` it is treated as uninitialized and it is the responsibility of the method to assign it a definite value.  The whole point of a swap method is to operate on values passed to it, but with `out` the values of those parameters are off limits because the caller is not required to pass an initialized variable.  Therefore, to answer your question, not only is using `ref` the superior solution, but using `out` is not a workable solution at all.

Answer (score 8):

By definition a `Swap()` function requires that the parameters passed have values. Therefore you should use `ref`.

Using `out` would imply that (and allow) uninitialized parameters could be passed (and in fact should not compile since you would be using an unassigned parameter)

Answer (score 1):

Definite assignment is a big deal in C#, it keeps you out of trouble by ensuring that your code has assigned a value to a variable before it is used.  The core reason that the language distinguishes between *ref* and *out*.  Other languages don't draw this distinction, they just have syntax for "pass by value" vs "pass by reference".  In VB.NET that's ByVal vs ByRef for example.  By using *out* instead of *ref* you clearly state the data flow and promise that the variable doesn't have to be assigned before the call and *will* be assigned afterwards.  The compiler verifies this and complains if you break that rule.

What you can't do is swap a "not assigned" state.  No syntax exists that lets you express that a variable is *not* assigned after an operation.  It therefore follows that you **must** use *ref*.  Nullable gives you options, not in scope here.